# repmgr standby switchover failed with ERROR: unable to connect via SSH to host "node IP", user ""

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

repmgr standby switchover -v
INFO: looking for configuration file in /etc
INFO: configuration file found at: "/etc/repmgr.conf"
NOTICE: executing switchover on node "DB-Test-02" (ID: 2)
WARNING: unable to connect to remote host "IP" via SSH
ERROR: unable to connect via SSH to host "IP", user ""

repmgrd service is stopped on primary,standbyand witness server.

I checked by connecting nodes from each other using SSH and that works.

Any hint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For successful switchover paswword less SSH is required. Try this.
https://tecadmin.net/password-less-ssh-login-setup/

2nd is, need to set up below commands in /etc/sudoers file.

```
    Defaults:postgres !requiretty
    postgres ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster 12 main stop, \
    /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster 12 main start, \
    /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster 12 main restart \
    /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster 12 main reload
```

In /etc/repmgr.conf file.

```
     service_start_command   = 'sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main start'
     service_stop_command    = 'sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main stop'
     service_restart_command = 'sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main restart'
     service_reload_command  = 'sudo pg_ctlcluster 12 main reload'
```

This works for me.